# 3d model viewer in Flash or Java

Tags: java, flash, 3d

I want to show a box in 3d on my website, and I was thinking to do it in Flash. How I can show a 3d model?
I need something very simple, it's a textured cube, no interaction required, just let the user pan and zoom.
There is a 3ds viewer in flash or something like that?

Java is also ok (but flash is preferred)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flash is signifficantly easier. Java can outperform Flash when using JOGL, but unless you're planing to have more than 200 polygons, Flash is just fine. You can use one of the big Flash 3D engine. Probably Sandy will be easier, since a sandy SkyBox is just what you need. Alternatively, you can just modify this little thing: http://www.advance-media.com/flash_10_as3_rotating_cube_3D.html